# Interested in embedded systems. Where to begin?

Tags: embedded

I'm a computer systems engineering student. i'm interested in designing embedded systems but i don't know where to begin learning this, and what topics are essentially needed to proceed in this domain.
So can you please tell me what topics do i have to study, and what books are available there in market or online that can help me???
please help me

p.s. normally as an engineering student i have basic knowledge of circuit theory and microcontroller realm.

Comment: I would say, buy yourself a PIC microcontroller and start by there. (try the different features at your disposal. i2C, SPI, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/).

From the site:

> Arduino is an open-source electronics prototyping platform based on flexible, easy-to-use hardware and software. It's intended for artists, designers, hobbyists, and anyone interested in creating interactive objects or environments.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good articles on the subject here:

http://www.ganssle.com/articles.htm